# Scalatra host static

Tags: jetty, scalatra

I can host scalatra static files (eg js) from /static if i register the default servlet for /static, How can I specify /static outside of the classpath, ie c:/path/static So that-way i can develop the web part separate from the embedded hosting.

Answer (score 0):

set the 'resourceBase' on the DefaultServlet to the location you want to serve content from